# In Flutter (and using Firebase realtime db), how do I get a snapshot of all of the users I have signed up?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I have a firebase realtime database with a hierarchy like such:

[image: firebase hierarchy]

How do I get it so that in my flutter app code, I can use the amount of users that are registered? (this is the amount of IDs available as children of the Users node in the database).

I've tried the following:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Users");
db.orderByKey().once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
    values.forEach((key, values){
      print(values[key]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you are after is the amount of IDs, why don't you take the length of the snapshot or increase a counter inside your `values.forEach()`?

If I am misinterpreting your answers please explain it more carefully and I will get back to you :)

Comment: I did actually try this, but I keep getting an issue saying that the foreach loop is being called on a null object :/ I don't understand how to fix it

Comment: Try to add `print(snapshot.toString());` before your map declaration to see if your if that contains anything. A question: Are you certain that `.value` is a thing and it is not called something else? I know this is a [node example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot.html#ref) but they need to append `.child()` before being able to get any values.